# How to sum columns from two related tables

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

I have two tables. `Invoices` and `invoice_items`. I am trying to get the sum of `total_payment` and total `quantity` for each client. I tried this query:

```
SELECT client_id,
sum(total_amount), sum(it.quantity) as days_hired
FROM  `invoices` `iv`
  join invoice_items it on  it.invoice_id=iv.invoice_id
group by client_id, it.invoice_id
```

But for client_id 14, I am getting total payment as 1908 instead of 636. Looks like the sum of this column gets repeated for every invoie_item. Any help will be appreciated.

```
invoices

invoice_id    client_id    total_payment
    36        13           530
    38        14           636


invoice_items

invoice_id    user_id      quantity     
36            2            2
38            3            2
38            4            2
38            5            2
```

Expected output:

```
13     530       2
14     636       6
```

Comment: pls post your expected output?

Comment: can you update the invoices and invoice items tables aslo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT client_id, sum(total_amount) as toal_amount, sum(it.quantity) as total_quantity
FROM  `invoices` `iv`
join
(
 select invoice_id,sum(quantity) as quantity from invoice_items group by invoice_id
)it on  it.invoice_id=iv.invoice_id
group by client_id, it.invoice_id
```

Comment: This seems to work. I will test with more invoices. There is a small fix though. sum(quantity) should be sum(quantity) as quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select i.*, ii.total_quantity
from invoices i
join (
  select invoice_id, sum(quantity) total_quantity from invoice_items
  group by invoice_id
) ii on i.invoice_id = ii.invoice_id
```